# Alerting through time series data in ELK

Tags: time-series, alert, elastic-stack

We are looking at ELK to do some alerting. is there a way to dump a time series data created through build in functions in ELK to dump it back to ELK to let us write alerts around it. For example:

There are ways to create a time series graph through Kibana by using Moving Average Aggregation or Holt-Winters double exponential smoothing. ELK also supports a Prediction model. 
What we want to do is when the Holt-winter output is less than X percent of the prediction we raise an alarm. 
But for that I need both the data points (Holt-winter and Predictive) back into ELK or some other database to calculate whether an alarm should be raised. 
How do we push these two data sets which are derivative of original data back into ELK or a database to raise alert

Comment: How about running it trough the pipline again with a elasticsearch input? You would need to tag or type accordingly to avoid a reindex loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write two derived data sets to different indices (one for each data set). And raise alerts based on the derived data sets.

To raise alerts, you can apply some external windowed streaming techniques; you may also want to take a look at elastic's "[watcher](https://www.elastic.co/products/watcher)" product.